# Converting Comma-Separated String to Numpy Array In Python 3

Tags: python, numpy, pyqtgraph

I'm using Python to read data from an Arduino sensor using PySerial in Python 3.

I want to plot the data using PyQtGraph, so I'm attempting to convert the string that is read from the sensor (288 comma separated values) to a Numpy array. However, I've tried a couple different methods and haven't gotten it to work.

Reading from the sensor works great with this code:

```
#Read the line of data from the sensor
line = sensor.readline()

#Decode the line to UTF-8 and print it
lineDecoded = line.decode("UTF-8")

print(lineDecoded)
```

Which gives me the correct output (288 comma separated values):

> 137,136,151,145,141,133,145,139,140,145,144,139,143,141,139,136,137,138,137,127,142,135,136,137,134,140,127,141,134,128,139,135,136,180,149,147,147,151,156,140,153,143,143,155,163,164,192,250,277,282,275,258,258,248,245,231,215,225,195,195,159,186,175,168,171,173,177,185,213,224,228,231,227,219,261,229,231,231,250,253,262,276,269,274,274,277,276,272,291,303,351,417,483,500,473,399,315,263,255,239,238,244,234,231,231,242,255,272,294,293,299,314,307,306,302,310,319,304,312,327,370,464,507,514,492,425,358,327,313,299,292,291,281,259,245,232,229,224,223,222,216,226,215,211,197,202,199,197,198,193,198,185,190,196,177,198,188,183,201,193,187,159,189,184,186,185,186,185,184,196,195,200,201,198,193,241,189,186,167,179,187,174,188,180,179,169,177,173,172,175,181,175,171,180,175,176,180,184,176,190,182,172,171,179,178,174,188,175,178,167,183,171,168,174,175,171,230,175,177,159,177,170,172,171,173,168,167,169,172,168,171,177,173,167,167,171,163,170,177,172,169,167,163,157,173,161,168,174,162,165,171,165,162,152,165,173,158,193,161,161,147,159,161,159,169,173,168,158,161,159,158,171,167,167,155,159,169,156,159,162,157,165,161,158,147,161,171,159,

From there, figured I'd just be able to pass `lineDecoded` to PyQtGraph's `plot` function, but after running this line of code

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,270,271,272,273,274,275,276,277,278,279,280,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,288]

y = [lineDecoded]

#Plot the data
pg.plot(x, y)
```

I got the error `Exception: X and Y arrays must be the same shape--got (288,) and (1,).`

I tried converting the string before passing it to PyQtGraph using various methods like `np.fromstring(lineDecoded)` and `np.array(list(lineDecoded)).ravel()` but none of the methods I've tried work.

Any ideas on how this could be accomplished?

**EDIT:** I've gone through the answers and none of them seem to be working, details in the comments for each response. Any hints would be great.

Comment: can you do a print y and type(y) and what's the output?

Comment: You can split it to a list and then into a numpy.array, `y = np.array(lineDecoded.split(","))`. But don't really have to you can just use it as a list for plotting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`line.decode()` returns a string (a `str`), not a `list`. So you are getting back a single entity, not 288 values.

Python has a method associated with strings that will take a string and split it into component parts. Calling the `.split()` method and giving it the substring to split upon, in this case a ',' should do the trick.

```
#Read the line of data from the sensor
line = sensor.readline()

#Decode the line to UTF-8 and print it
lineDecoded = line.decode("UTF-8")


values = [int(i) for i in lineDecoded.split(',')]    # <<< this should work
                                                     # added a list
                                                     # comprehension to 
                                                     # convert values to integers


x = range(1,289)                   # <<< this is preferred if you need 
                                   # a range of numbers from 1 to 288

y = values

#Plot the data
pg.plot(x, y)
```

NOTE: as @umutto mentions in a comment above, for plotting purposes, there should be no need to convert the values to a numpy array. A list should do just fine.

But, if for some reason you find that you want/need an array:

```
y = np.array(values)
```

Comment: Thanks - I used your advice on the split function and got `TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type pyqtgraph`, so I modified the code to `lineDecoded = lineDecoded[:-2]` (to remove extra figures) and  `yValues = lineDecoded.split(",")` `y = np.array(yValues).astype(np.int)`. The error messages are now gone, but the PyQtGraph popup window crashes upon opening and doesn't show any data. Any ideas why this would happen (in Jupyter)?

Comment: Question for @AggroCrag: can you produce a simplified version of the graph you are trying to produce with simple, well-defined data? 
i.e. feed into pg.plot(x, y) a short list for each:
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [5, 6, 7]

I often find the source of my problems by creating well known data to see if that works. If it does, then I start to look at my real data. If it does not, then I start to look at my implementation (i.e. is Jupyter set up to display PyQtGraphs, etc, etc).
Sorry I can't be more specific.
NOTE: our answers seems satisfactory in solving the original question posed.

Comment: I went ahead and use the code you mentioned, and the Python window that popped up for that simple dataset crashed as well. Must be a system problem on my end. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.split#str.split) method for converting the line to a `list` of strings. Also as @Alien suggests, you should use the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function for getting `x`, instead of enumerating all the values manually.

```
y = [int(i) for i in lineDecoded.split(',')]
x = range(1,289)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, lineDecoded)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried your method in Jupyter Notebook, and it threw the error `matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend`. I tried to change the backend with the following code: `import matplotlib`
`matplotlib.use('TkAgg')`
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt' but it throws the error 'UserWarning: This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect because the backend has already been chosen`. Do I need to ditch Jupyter to get your method to work?

Comment: Depending on how you initialized your Jupyter Notebook, the matplotlib backend might already be set up. If this is the case, trying to set it again causes this error. This conversation, albeit for Spyder, describes what is happening with your Jupyter Notebook. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spyderlib/tRwgqEAIyvs

Comment: Yeah, I guess I can't change the backend on Jupyter... I'll stick with PyQtGraph. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With a copy/paste of your string:

```
In [341]: astring="""137,136,151,145,141,133,145,139,140,145,144,139,143,141,139
     ...: ,136,137,138,137,127,142,135,136,137,134,140,127,141,134,128,139,135,1
     ...: 36,180,149,147,147,151,156,140,153,143,143,155,163,164,192,250,277,282
     ...: ...
,147,159,161,159,169,173,168,158,161,159,158,171,167,167,155,159,169,1
     ...: 56,159,162,157,165,161,158,147,161,171,159"""
```

`split(',')` produces a list of strings.  If I wrap that in `np.array`, I get an array of strings:

```
In [342]: np.array(astring.split(','))
Out[342]: 
array(['137', '136', '151', '145', '141', '133', '145', '139', '140',
       ...
       '162', '157', '165', '161', '158', '147', '161', '171', '159'], 
      dtype='<U3')
```

I need to tell it to convert the strings to integers:

```
In [343]: np.array(astring.split(','),int)
Out[343]: 
array([137, 136, 151, 145, 141, 133, 145, 139, 140, 145, 144, 139, 143,
       141, 139, 136, 137, 138, 137, 127, 142, 135, 136, 137, 134, 140,
...., 165, 161, 158, 147, 161,
       171, 159])
In [344]: _.shape
Out[344]: (288,)
```

The first time I tried it, the string ended with a comma: `"8,147,161,171,159,"`.  The split then included an empty string, which `np.array` could not convert to integer.  I edited that out.  I could also have removed it from the list of strings with indexing, `[:-1]`.

If it works to pass the list of strings (after split) to the plot function, it's because that function performed this same sort of `np.array(..., int)` (or float) conversion.

```
[int(i) for i in astring.split(',')]
```

can be used to create a list of integers.

Comment: Thanks for the info on indexing. using `[:-2]` allowed to me to trim off the newline character and the comma at the end. And I used your suggestion to convert the strings to integer (as mentioned in the response to @E. Ducateme) but am still unable to get a working Python window to open to show the PyQtGraph plot and not crash.

Comment: `numpy` users are more likely to use `matplotlib` for plotting than `PyQtGraph`.  You may need to ask a separate `PyQtGraph` question focusing on getting that package working.

Answer (score 0):

```
lineDecoded = [137,136,151,145,141,133,145,139,140,145,144,139,143,141,139,136,137,138,137,127,142,135,136,137,134,140,127,141,134,128,139,135,136,180,149,147,147,151,156,140,153,143,143,155,163,164,192,250,277,282,275,258,258,248,245,231,215,225,195,195,159,186,175,168,171,173,177,185,213,224,228,231,227,219,261,229,231,231,250,253,262,276,269,274,274,277,276,272,291,303,351,417,483,500,473,399,315,263,255,239,238,244,234,231,231,242,255,272,294,293,299,314,307,306,302,310,319,304,312,327,370,464,507,514,492,425,358,327,313,299,292,291,281,259,245,232,229,224,223,222,216,226,215,211,197,202,199,197,198,193,198,185,190,196,177,198,188,183,201,193,187,159,189,184,186,185,186,185,184,196,195,200,201,198,193,241,189,186,167,179,187,174,188,180,179,169,177,173,172,175,181,175,171,180,175,176,180,184,176,190,182,172,171,179,178,174,188,175,178,167,183,171,168,174,175,171,230,175,177,159,177,170,172,171,173,168,167,169,172,168,171,177,173,167,167,171,163,170,177,172,169,167,163,157,173,161,168,174,162,165,171,165,162,152,165,173,158,193,161,161,147,159,161,159,169,173,168,158,161,159,158,171,167,167,155,159,169,156,159,162,157,165,161,158,147,161,171,159]

x = range(1,289)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, lineDecoded)
```